# Yii2 authclient not returning email id of user

Tags: yii2, yii-components, yii2-advanced-app

Am using yii2-authclient for facebook login for my site, Am getting response like this

```
yii\authclient\clients\Facebook Object ( [authUrl] => https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup [tokenUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token [apiBaseUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com [scope] => email [version] => 2.0 [clientId] => *******[clientSecret] => ********[_returnUrl:yii\authclient\BaseOAuth:private] => http://www.usermodule.com/index.php?r=site%2Fauth&authclient=facebook [_curlOptions:yii\authclient\BaseOAuth:private] => Array ( ) [_accessToken:yii\authclient\BaseOAuth:private] => yii\authclient\OAuthToken Object ( [tokenParamKey] => access_token [tokenSecretParamKey] => oauth_token_secret [createTimestamp] => 1436772538 [_expireDurationParamKey:yii\authclient\OAuthToken:private] => [_params:yii\authclient\OAuthToken:private] => Array ( [access_token] => ****************************** [expires] => 5182933 ) ) [_signatureMethod:yii\authclient\BaseOAuth:private] => Array ( ) [_id:yii\authclient\BaseClient:private] => facebook [_name:yii\authclient\BaseClient:private] => [_title:yii\authclient\BaseClient:private] => [_userAttributes:yii\authclient\BaseClient:private] => [_normalizeUserAttributeMap:yii\authclient\BaseClient:private] => [_viewOptions:yii\authclient\BaseClient:private] => [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => ) Array ( [name] => **** [id] => *****)
```

This is my config

```
 'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
        'facebook' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',              
            'clientId' => '***',
            'clientSecret' => '****',

        ],
    ],
]
```

Am able to get username, user id but not user email id why? What else I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes finally got the solution,

when you make graph api request

```
$this->makeSignedRequest('me');
```

replace it with

```
$this->makeSignedRequest('me?fields=id,name,email');
```

either you are doing using facebook sdk or using yii2-eauth extension like me.
if you are using yii2-eauth then you need to change this in vendor/nodge/yii2-eauth/src/services/FacebookOAuth2Service.php

then add this line to read email attribute

```
$this->attributes['email'] = $info['email'];
```

Note: I tried yii way of passing argument like

```
$this->makeSignedRequest('me',array('fields'=>'id,email');
```

didn't work for me.

Source of solution: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile/5.0.0

Comment: easily modificate passing arguments and it'll work `$info = $this->makeSignedRequest('me',array(
   'query' => array(
    'fields' => 'email, name, birthday, gender, link, first_name, last_name, age_range',
   ),
  ));`

Comment: when to call $this->makeSignedRequest? sitecontroller?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution with the help of above solutions.

In yii2-authclient/clients/Facebook.php there is a function initUserAttributes() in which

```
 return $this->api('me', 'GET');
```

replace it with

```
 return $this->api('me?fields=id,name,email', 'GET');
```

Answer (score 1):

Really there is some mistake from yii2 eauth extension.

Firstly setting scope params in web.php

```
            'facebook' => array(
                // register your app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
                'clientId' => '454208034652365',
                'clientSecret' => '0e7161949129d4120cc5ac7d79f89098',
                'class' => 'nodge\eauth\services\FacebookOAuth2Service',
                'scope'        => [
                    'email'
                    ]
            ),
```

Then can you use like the following

```
  $info = $eauth->makeSignedRequest('me', [
                'query' => [
                    'fields' => join(',', [
                        'id',
                        'name',
                        'link',
                        'email'
                    ])
                ]
            ]);
            echo $info['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for using Yii2-authclient you have to configure(main.php) like that:-
    inside components array write
    'authClientCollection' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
            'clients' => [
                'facebook' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                    'clientId' => 'your Client-Id',
                    'clientSecret' => 'your Client-secret',
                ],

            ],
        ],
    in controller inside actions method write:-
    auth' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
                 ],

then create successCallback function like
public function successCallback($client)
        {
            $attributes= $client->getUserAttributes();
            print_r($attributes);
} 
then you got all attributes which are shared by Facebook(like email, firstname etc).
```

Comment: Please read my question again, am getting response from facebook which I have shared in my question but in that am not getting email

Comment: replace your config with given solution, then check

Comment: Done! response I got was Array ( [name] => ****** [id] => ***** ) .  No email id

Comment: are you register your app on developers.facebook.com

Comment: yea I have else I wont get even this response right

Answer (score 0):

```
'facebook' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
    'clientId' => '****',
    'clientSecret' => '*****',
 ],
```

That is enough. But sometime you still can not get email address because some facebook user do not has an email address:

- facebook user register by phone
- facebook user register by email but email not verified

You have to catch it to notify the user.
I don't know have any other exceptions. if user have an email but your app can not get that email address, let's check `email` permission in list `Approved Items` in "status and review" page on facebook developer to know why. 
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/review-status/

Comment: I have fb account by email Id, I tested with my friend account also its same no email in response. Approved items email,public profile, user_friends shows approved by default.